# Tomcat 404 page error

Tags: java, grails, tomcat8

I'm getting 404 page when deploying my application under tomcat, there's no error during startup in logs every things seems normal but when I try to access application in web browser it give 404 tomcat error page, has anybody faced similar error? Following are details about environment.

GRAILS:

```
$ grails -version
| Grails Version: 3.1.5
| Groovy Version: 2.4.6
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_111
```

JAVA:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_111"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b15)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b15, mixed mode)

$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_111
```

TOMCAT:

```
$ /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh version
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.0.35
Server built:   May 11 2016 21:57:08 UTC
Server number:  8.0.35.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_111-b15
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

Comment: What version of grails are you using?  Grails 3.2.0 has a known issue.  Please try Grails 3.2.2 instead.

Comment: I'm using grails 3.1.5 added, updated my post with grails info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing following lines from `build.gradle` it worked.

```
compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-rest"     
compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-interceptors"     
compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-services"     
compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-datasource"       
compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding"      
compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-async"        
compile "org.grails:grails-logging"     
provided "org.grails:grails-plugin-domain-class"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue with Grails 3.2.0 documented with a workaround and resolved in Grails 3.2.2.

[Grails 404 with Tomcat 3.2.0](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10196)

Comment: I had a look into this thread before, didn't help. I don't have groovy-ant dependency in my build.gradle at all.